# Ubuntu 19.04 touchpad, external usb mouse clicks not working

Tags: 19.04

I use a Lenovo ThinkPad L430 and have been been using Ubuntu 19.04 for months.
Today suddenly my touchpad's left click stopped working and when I connected an external USB mouse the results were same.

After a restart clicks work for a couple of minutes but then they stop working.

Comment: `rmmod psmouse && modprobe psmouse proto=imps` in a root shell. Does this work?

Comment: What does this command do, I searched but couldn't figure out what this means.

Comment: Did that work for you? It basically removes the kernel driver responsible for handling your mouse and loads it in a different mode so that it can recognize your mouse or touchpad.

Comment: No that didn't help at all